# DNS server can resolve 'example.com' but not 'example.com/website'

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns, ddns

I have setup a DDNS 'example.com' pointing to a device in my home sitting behind a router with dynamic IP x.x.x.x. In my device I am running a website at 'example.com/website'. I have taken care of the port forwarding and everything works well everywhere except in one particular laptop running Windows 10 in my workplace.

I can see (using dig in the Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10) that 'example.com' is pointing correctly to the IP x.x.x.x, so the DNS server seems to be resolving well that domain name. However, when I try to resolve 'example.com/website', the connections times out. Going instead directly to 'x.x.x.x/website' in the browser works...

Importantly, using other devices in the same network (eg. Linux in the same machine, Windows 10 in a different computer or even my phone connected to Wifi) work flawlessly. I have checked that the DNS servers are the same in all of the devices I tried. It seems that the reason could be some setting in this particular machine... I have tried to run "ipconfig /flushdns" and other related commands, but it didn't help.

If someone could help me, I would appreciate it. I can give more information if needed.

**EDIT: the issue is solved now, I had forgotten about a line I added to the hosts file pointing the domain to my internal IP address, so it was no wonder that it didn't work outside... Thanks for the help!**

Comment: Could you clarify what actual failure you're getting in which program? "Cannot resolve" is a very different thing from "connection times out".

Comment: Which DDNS service are you using? Have you port-forwarded port 80 in the router to your device? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @user1686 you are right, I don't get an actual failure, I just see that the connection times out. Using 'dig example.com/website' doesn't return an IP address.

Comment: @harrymc I use No-IP but as far as I can see they the DDNS is pointing to the correct IP address. I have port-forwarded port 80 and I can access it from other devices outside my home network.

Comment: The result from 'dig' is normal - `/website` is the HTTP path, it's not part of the DNS domain name. HTTP paths are never handled through DNS resolution. Are you able to access just `example.com` or specifically `http://example.com` through either the web browser or `curl -v`?

Comment: Are you trying to go from inside the network to the internet and back again? Many consumer-grade routers do not support Loopback.

Comment: @user1686 I figured it thanks to you! By doing curl I noticed that it was pointing to the wrong IP address (the local one in my LAN) and after checking the hosts file I found the problem: I was pointing the DNS to my server's LAN IP address (I did it a long time ago because I was homeworking for many months), so it's no wonder it didn't work... So it was my fault all along, I am sorry... I thank you for all the help!

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not the case as the problem does not occur in the same network as my server... Indeed I have that problem at home (my router does not support NAT Loopback as you suggested) but I'm hosting a DNS splitter in my server that takes care of that.

In any case, my problem is now solved, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster has solved his error himself.

Comment: @harrymc Agreed, and thanks again!

Comment: That's not really a valid close reason. If you've solved the problem then post an answer -- even if it's your own question.

Comment: @user1686 I have replied to my question, but can only accept it in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved now, I had forgotten about a line I added to the hosts file pointing the domain to my internal IP address, so it was no wonder that it didn't work outside... Thanks for the help of all those who replied!

Answer (score 1):

Your question reveals a misunderstanding about how DNS and web servers work.

A DNS server will only resolve a host name. If you access "https://website.domain.com/whatever" with a browser, DNS is only concerned with the "website.domain.com" part (which it will translate to an IP address). The "/whatever" part is not sent to DNS by the browser and is not "resolved" by it. If you ask a tool like `dig` (which queries DNS) to resolve a query like "website.domain.com/whatever" it will not know what to do with it.

The "/whatever" part is only seen by the web server running on the host that is resolved by DNS and addressed by the client (your browser running on your PC). The web server software will use this (together with other information it finds in the request) to determine what content to serve.

Comment: You are right, I am not very experienced with these issues. Thank you for taking the time to explain, I appreciate it.